# Get Bluebird Promise resolved value

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

I have Bluebird promise:

```
return Promise.props({
    something: getSomething() // returns 2
})
.then(function (data) {
    return {
        a: 1,
        b: data.something
    };
});
```

I expect to get:
`{ a: 1, b: 2 }`

But I get instead a Promise, why's that?

```
{
    isFulfilled: false
    isRejected: false
}
```

Comment: Yes then returns a promise. Otherwise how would you chain off it? The value you return is the value of the promise then returns not the value of the then.

Comment: @torazaburo and how to get it's value?  `.value()` can not be used as am not knowing when Promise fulfills https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#value---dynamic

Comment: @Ultra: Just use another `then` callback… Notice that you can only consume promises asynchronously.

Comment: You get its value by doing `promise.then(function(value) { /* value is the value */ })`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30180679/1348195